# Find absolute origin of TextField which is in nested UIStackView

Tags: ios, position, uitextfield, uistackview

I want to move base view when keyboard appear in oder to make suer text field is appear. Since my text field is in side of nested UIStackView when I call textField.origin I get origin relative to UISTackView only. I want to get origin relative to root view (absolute origin). How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the frame of textField to window co-ordinate base using

```
let convertedFrameToWindow = self.textView.convert(self.textView.frame, to: nil)
```

This will give you the frame of your textField/textView mapped to window's coordinate space now you can use it to compare with keyboard frame

Hope it helps